# Print PDF to specific folder with specific name with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, printing

I have a folder C:\Users\User1\FolderForPDF, and I have Excel workbooks and a Pdf printer with the name of "PdfPrinter1".

After I edit workbook as I need to, I would like to have a macro, that would print first worksheet in my workbook to PDF. I need it to have a name that is in Cell A1 on this first worksheet, and add "_archive" to that (so eg. "worksheet12_archive"). The PDF should be printed to the folder I listed above. The resolution needs to be set to 600. I want it to go through my pdf printer (not through saving as pdf or printing through Microsoft to PDF).

I would like everything to be set in that "Save as" popup window (suggested name, saving folder).

I know about the .ExportAsFixedFormat and this does the job for me for one other specific thing, but for this one I need it to actually go through printing, because this "save as pdf" makes the resolution way bellow my requirement.

Is that possible to acchive or am I looking at something to much for vba?

Comment: PDFPrinter part: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748166/word-macro-export-high-quality-pdf-with-images). Save As with file name from cell value part (same same for save as/pdf printer): [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350314/vba-save-as-pdf-with-filename-as-cell-value). At least a starting point would be have a look over those QA's and start from there.

Comment: @SamuelEverson Thank you, but the first post didn't work for me, maybe because it was done for Word? Also the second one is with .ExportAsFixedFormat which like I said don't do the job for me on this case.

Comment: @KJ but how do I get to using MS Print to PDF with all the criteria I wrote in the post?